# c# xml deserilization

Tags: c#

How to deserialize an XML like this, I have some problems with the Message Array.

```
<EventSources>
<Source>
 <Event>
  <Id>9</Id> 
  <Message LcId="1033">Text9</Message> 
  <Message LcId="1031">Message 9</Message> 
  <Message LcId="1034">Text9</Message> 
 </Event>

 <Event>
  <Id>10</Id> 
  <Message LcId="1033">Text10</Message> 
  <Message LcId="1031">Message 10</Message> 
  <Message LcId="1034">Text10</Message> 
 </Event>

</Source>
</EventSources>
```

I tried to serialize this code but the Output does not match

```
public class EventSources
{
    #region Variables
    private List<Event> _Source = new List<Event>();
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<Event> Source
    {
        get { return _Source; }
        set { _Source = value; }
    }


    #endregion

    public EventSources() { }

    public void AddError(Event error)
    {
        _Source.Add(error);
    }
}

public class Event
{
    #region Variables
    private int _Id;
    private List<Message> _languageEntries = new List<Message>();
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [XmlElement()]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    public List<Message> LanguageEntries
    {
        get { return _languageEntries; }
        set { _languageEntries = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public Event() { }

    public Event(int id)
    {
        _Id = Id;
    }

    public void Add(Message entry)
    {
        _languageEntries.Add(entry);
    }
}

public class Message
{
    #region Variables
    private string _lang = string.Empty;
    private string _text = string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [XmlAttribute("LcId")]
    public string LcId
    {
        get { return _lang; }
        set { _lang = value; }
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public Message() { }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
<EventSources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Source>
    <Event>
      <Id>5</Id>
      <LanguageEntries>
        <Message LcId="5">kjhfdkgdskfkgds</Message>
        <Message LcId="554">kjhfskfkgds</Message>
      </LanguageEntries>
    </Event>
  </Source>
  <Messages />
</EventSources>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[XmlElement("Message")]
public List<Message> LanguageEntries
{
    get { return _languageEntries; }
    set { _languageEntries = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a schema file for this xml, use xsd.exe to generate the matching C# objects. Once you've generated an object representation of the XML schema, you can use methods from the XmlSerializer class to serialize and deserialize XML files.